# Does the galera cluster have to have an odd number of nodes?

Tags: php, mysql, galera

I currently have 8 nodes in my Galera cluster, but I saw a video that suggests to have only an odd number of nodes (3,5,7,9,ect).

Is this true? And will I have any issues having 8 nodes in my cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, 8 is OK.  The "quorum" mechanism needs a majority.  If you have at least 3 nodes (and only one fails), the remaining nodes can establish a quorum.

If your 8 nodes are split with 4 in each of two datacenters, then a datacenter outage would kill the entire cluster.  To protect against datacenter failure, you should spread the nodes 'evenly' across 3 (or more) datacenters.  For 8 nodes:  3+3+2 is the only safe split.  4+3+1 or 4+2+2 would kill the cluster if the '4' datacenter went down.

How well is the 8-node cluster working?  (That's the biggest one I have heard of.)

Comment: Hi there, I am still experimenting on how to optimize the galara cluster to perform optimally. Should I distribute the queries across all 8 nodes, or should I point the requests to all one node?

Comment: A `SELECT` may involve a lot or processing; hence, it is almost always better to spread `SELECTs` across the nodes in the cluster.  (I like using "round robin" in a load balancer.)  Writes can be trickier, but again spreading them around is often optimal.

Comment: ADDENDA:  With "weighting", you can make 4+2+2 or 4+3+1 safe.